# where should I set up the $watch in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have an angular directive that is supposed to display some data structure.
the data structure itself is supposed to be selected using a select box.

```
<div>There are {{blocks.length}} blocks in this blocks set</div>
<select ng-model="block" ng-options="b.name for b in blocks"></select><br>
<myblock block="block"></myblock>
```

Now when a different block is selected using the select the `myblock` directive does not automatically update to reflect the change.

I assume this is because I have to $watch the block parameter 
(which is defined as "block":"=" ) in the directive's (isolated) scope.

Where (in the code) would be the appropriate place to set up this watch? 
Are there any common patterns for this?

Is there a way to tell the "myblock" to just "refresh" itself?

Comment: is $scope.block an object or a primitive? your watch should work if it's primitive

Comment: I see block is an object, are you using a deep watch? $scope.$watch('block',function() { ... },true);

Comment: You can put it in the 'link' or 'controller' portion of your directive

Answer (score 0):

From my comments above, your watch should work, if you add true as the last argument:

```
    <div ng-app="pageModule"
        ng-controller="parentCtrl">
        <div>There are {{blocks.length}} blocks in this blocks set</div>
        <select ng-model="block" ng-options="b.name for b in blocks"></select><br>
        <div myblock block="block"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- 3rd Party -->

    <script>

var pageModule = angular.module('pageModule',[])
.controller('parentCtrl',function($scope) {
    $scope.blocks = [
        { name : 'green' },
        { name : 'blue'  },
        { name : 'red'   }
    ];
})
.directive('myblock',function() {
    return {
        scope : { block : '=' },
        link  : function($scope,$element,$attrs) {
            $scope.$watch('block',function(s) {
                if(s) {
                    console.log('block: ' + s.name);
                }
            },true);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Very likely I was missing the deep watch flag...
when working like this - where would you put the actual linking logic? considering the fact that when the block changes I actuall want to "re-link" the dom based on the updated object?

Comment: This will update with the correct value, without any changes: '<div myblock block="block">{{block.name}}</div>'. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: no.. in my directive I am doing some pre-processing of the information in the block. I thought I would do this in the link function but I actually need to re-do it whenever the block changes and from the watch listener I cant call the link function because it will bind the watch again... :(